# Finding all uses of a Java class in reference equality in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, refactoring

I want to identify all instances of reference equality for a particular class and replace them with `equals`. Is there a technique or tool in IntelliJ that I can use for this? Can I filter Find Usages down to "usage in `==`" somehow?

Essentially, I would like this tool to list:

1. Instances of this class and sub-classes
2. That are used in reference equality

It is okay if it does not detect reference equality checks of instances of superclasses of this class.

Comment: Just to get you started on some research, you may find the "Structural search and replace" feature useful. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/structural-search-and-replace.html It comes with some prebuilt templates that you can explore to build your own queries. Very useful for some super advanced refactoring on large code bases.

Comment: Thank you, @Strelok. I tried using that but it doesn't look like I can specify a constraint of "LHS is of type A".

EDIT: In classic form, I was just missing the obvious and right after posting I saw it front of me: it's the obviously named "Type" filter which you place a fully qualified name after.

Comment: @Strelok I made this an answer. Thanks a bunch for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right way to do this is:

1. Edit > Find > Search Structurally...
2. Use the following template

```
$LHS$ == $RHS$
```

3. Click the `$LHS$` section and add a Filter on the right of `Type` set to your type fully-qualified (in my case `roshan.model.Quantity`) and select 'Within Type Hierarchy'
4. Repeat with the `$RHS$` (you may optionally set the `Type` to `model.Quantity|null` if you want to include null-checks)
5. Run Find

This will find you exactly the set of reference equality checks of type LHS to type RHS including sub-classes on both sides. Ha! Amazing.

Comment: Wow this is perfect